# Shiny: Two conditional panels in a row - how to have them fill the entire row if only one is showing?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a fluid row that contains two conditional panels.  I would to make it so that if only one is being displayed, it takes up the entire row (width = 12), whereas if both are showing they both get equal space (width = 6).

I have attempted to use multiple conditional panels based on logic of whether one or both are turned on, but it ends up showing all of the panels regardless of the value of either of the inputs.

When I comment out either the first two conditional panels OR the 3rd one, the logic works fine - so it isn't the individual logic, it's something that isn't working when all 3 are evaluated.

So, is there something I'm doing wrong here?  Is there a better option than having multiple conditional panels for the same content, such as a method for having them automatically take up as much width as is available?

```r
fluidRow(
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.chart_toggle && !input.table_toggle",
                       box(title = "Chart",
                           width = 12,
                           collapsible = F,
                           collapsed = F,
                           plotOutput("newplot")
                      )
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.table_toggle && !input.chart_toggle",
                       box(title = "Table",
                           width = 12,
                           collapsible = F,
                           collapsed = F,
                           DTOutput("table")
                       )
      ),
      
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.chart_toggle && input.table_toggle",
                       box(title = "Chart",
                           width = 6,
                           collapsible = F,
                           collapsed = F,
                           plotOutput("newplot")
                       ),
      
                       box(title = "Table",
                           width = 6,
                           collapsible = F,
                           collapsed = F,
                           DTOutput("table")
                       )
      )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, alternatively you can take the conditions out of the conditional panel and render the panels in the `server` side using `renderUI`. There you can put the conditions you want for rendering different panels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple identical ids for different inputs/outputs is never a good idea. It will most certainly result in unexpected behaviour.

That said, using `conditionalPanel` seems to complicate things a bit.

As @Meisam stated in the comments, you can use `renderUI` and then put the conditions there.

Another alternative would be to use `{shinyjs}` to hide and show the cards, and then update them as required.

Here is a reprex:

[image: shinyjs+updateCards showcase]

#### `global.R`

```r
library(shiny)
```

#### `ui.R`

```r
ui <- bs4Dash::bs4DashPage(
  header = bs4Dash::dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = bs4Dash::dashboardSidebar(),
  body = bs4Dash::dashboardBody(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    checkboxInput(
      inputId = "chart_toggle",
      label = "Show chart",
      value = TRUE
    ),
    checkboxInput(
      inputId = "table_toggle",
      label = "Show table",
      value = TRUE
    ),
    fluidRow(
      bs4Dash::bs4Card(
        id = "chart_card",
        title = "Chart",
        width = 6,
        collapsible = FALSE,
        plotOutput("newplot")
      ),
      bs4Dash::bs4Card(
        id = "table_card",
        title = "Table",
        width = 6,
        collapsible = FALSE,
        DT::DTOutput(outputId = "table")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

#### `server.R`

```r
server <- \(input, output, session) {
  output$newplot <- renderPlot({
    plot(
      x = iris$Sepal.Length,
      y = iris$Petal.Width,
      col = iris$Species,
      xlab = "Sepal Length",
      ylab = "Petal Width",
      pch = 19
    )
  })
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(
      iris,
      options = list(scrollX = TRUE)
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$chart_toggle, input$table_toggle), {
    chart_toggle <- input$chart_toggle
    table_toggle <- input$table_toggle
    if (chart_toggle && !table_toggle) {
      shinyjs::hide(id = "table_card")
      bs4Dash::updatebs4Card(
        id = "chart_card",
        action = "update",
        options = list(width = 12)
      )
      shinyjs::show(id = "chart_card")
    }

    if (!chart_toggle && table_toggle) {
      shinyjs::hide(id = "chart_card")
      bs4Dash::updatebs4Card(
        id = "table_card",
        action = "update",
        options = list(width = 12)
      )
      shinyjs::show(id = "table_card")
    }

    if (chart_toggle && table_toggle) {
      bs4Dash::updatebs4Card(
        id = "chart_card",
        action = "update",
        options = list(width = 6)
      )
      bs4Dash::updatebs4Card(
        id = "table_card",
        action = "update",
        options = list(width = 6)
      )
      shinyjs::show(id = "chart_card")
      shinyjs::show(id = "table_card")
    }
    
    if (!chart_toggle && !table_toggle) {
      shinyjs::hide(id = "chart_card")
      shinyjs::hide(id = "table_card")
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get not having inputs with the same id, but I wasn't aware that having outputs with the same id would be an issue. I suppose there are variables that change with the state of the outputs that probably get messed up.

Comment: Yes having outputs with the same id is an issue. If you do you will get the error `Uncaught Duplicate binding for ID` on your browser on inspection. And probably none of the outputs will be rendered.